# Error while running testng.XML from Pom.xml

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I am getting error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project "Project Name": Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.report.PojoStackTraceWriter.getThrowable()Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/SafeThrowable;
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:309)"
while running testng.xml from pom.xml
```

Please note My maven is hosted in nexus.

My Pom.xml is below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Automationframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>Framework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.53.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.edbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>edbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
              <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
              <version>2.53.0</version>
              <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
              <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
              <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.ingres.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>iijdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.0-4.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
             <version>3.11</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-grouper</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>


    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                    <skip>false</skip>


                </configuration>


            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the solution by adding below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-java5</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```